# Does chromas unlock a skin i don't own?

Tags: league-of-legends

With this new lunar missions we are able to get at least this chromas:

[image]

Will I get the Warring Kingdoms Garen skin if I forge my Golden Revel Token into that bundle? That is buying that Garen's golden chroma will unlock me that Garen's default skin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you still have to buy the skin itself.

However, if you get the chroma, you can take as long as you want to purchase the base skin. For example, if you received the Garen chroma today, you could wait until next year to unlock the base skin and the chroma would automatically be unlocked at the same time.